# Adding a query to a HTML Page

Tags: html, css, networking, ip

I have built a Status Page for my servers with HTML and CSS, and instead of updating the Server Status every time one of them goes down, I was wondering if it's possible to add something to query the IP's of the server every 10m or so, and if the query fails, to turn the status button to RED.

Here's what I'm working with: https://status.floridastaterp.org

Any help is largely appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: with only html you can't

Comment: So is there absolutely anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: You have to check if server responding every 10 mins, you can do it with a serverside language like php i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without PHP, for that use **javascript** and make a **ajax call**:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // You change the status of button
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

And to call it every 10min, warp your function with:

```
setTimeout(request(),1000);
```

---

```
function request(){
            if(response == true){
                // This makes it unable to send a new request 
                // unless you get response from last request
                response = false;
                var req = $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"https://status.floridastaterp.org"
                });

                req.done(function(){
                    console.log("Request successful!");

                    // This makes it able to send new request on the next interval
                    response = true;
                });
            }

            setTimeout(request(),1000);
        }

        request();
```

Comment: Nice ! Hope you enjoy your js coding ^^
If you can validate my answer as accepted, much appreciate